# Allow document editing for non-google users

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using Google Drive API to create documents and share them with others.
Everything was OK until I had to send invitation to collaborate to non-google user.
First of all, since only Google account owners can edit the document, I set that anyone with link can edit.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{FILE_ID}/permissions?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
{
    "role": "writer",
    "type": "anyone",
    "withLink": true
}
```

And then I sent the invitation to collaborate to the user:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{FILE_ID}/permissions?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
{
    "role": "writer",
    "type": "user",
    "value": "******@outlook.com"
}
```

But, instead of shareable link, invitation to join Google is sent to that user.
`...GlWBwxEs/edit?invite=CI-zzNYL&pli=1`
How can I send shareable link to non-google users instead of invitation to create google account?

Answer (score 0):

when you dont have a google account, you can collaborate only anonymously.

once you add a non-google account to the sharing list, as of a few months ago Google will attempt to get the user to sign-up for a google account. once the user signs-up, google changes the sharing setting to point to the new google address (instead of the outlook.com one in your case).

this only happens when you explicitly share to a non google account. if you instead allow anonymous edits you can just send them directly the link.

Comment: I see, but, is it possible to send shareable link to people I invite?
It's a bit strange, that anyone with link can edit, but people with invitation can't.

Comment: Once I remove that email address from the list of people I share the document with, the link sent do that person becomes redirects to document editing, not invitation.

Comment: After removing outlook account from sharing list it becomes able to edit. That's what I don't understand.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: after our chat i understand better the situation and changed my answer. cc @aibrean good catch.

Comment: Okay, now I see. 
Is that possible to check whether the email is a Google account and, if not, send the link to anonymous edit using Drive API?
I am writing application which could create and share documents with any user without need to create Google account, so I can't email the link manually.

Comment: there are ways but its a separate question and i believe is covered elsewhere in s.o. there isnt an api thou.

Comment: here is one workarround: first share only for anonymous edit, and copy the sharing link. then add the emails as editors and edit the custom sharing message to include your copied url, telling users to use that one if they dont have google accounts.